# Where to get the Oracle TKPROF.exe utility?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, profiling

Does anyone know which Oracle installer package contains the TKPROF.exe utility?   I installed "Oracle client base" and also tried installing "Oracle Client Runtime 11g"  and while that install has sqlplus.exe  and tnsping.exe  , it is missing tkprof.exe .    I am using TOAD 11g and it seems to require a directory location of that file in order to perform a trace.   I am trying to avoid installing the full blown Oracle on my development system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think tkprof only comes with the server.  Although a client can request the creation of a trace file, the trace file will be created and stored on the server.  If you need access to the server to get the file, you might as well run tkprof on the server.

But if that's still a problem, you can copy tkprof.exe and the related files from the server's /bin/ directory, and then run it locally.  I'm not sure exactly what files are necessary, but it worked for me on 11.2.0.3 on Windows by copying all 279 MB of files.

But if you're using Toad, and doing the kind of work that requires tkprof, you really ought to have a local installation of Oracle.